# Java - Transparent window on Dual Monitor

Tags: java, transparency, foreground, multiple-monitors

I want to use a fullscreen transparent Window in Java. 
Looks like no Problem.

```
Window ovl = new Window(null) ;

ovl.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,200));
ovl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
ovl.setVisible(true);
ovl.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

// ovl.setSize((1680*2), 100); //- OK
ovl.setSize((1680*2)+1, 100); //- NotOK
```

And I have a Dualmonitor setup. First 1680 and second 1920 in Width.
When I expand my form larger than the Double size of my first monitor the Window looses all Transperancy. (Same when I move the Window to the Second Monitor)
Its like when most of the Window is on the Second Monitor.

And it doesnt even change back but remains this way.

System: Linux Mint Debian edition and OpenJDK 7